# Extracting blocks of a large data set with non-specific separators

Tags: bash, data-wrangling

I'm working on a linux server and have a very large dataset that is structured as follows:

```
long block of data
;
long block of data
;
long block of data
;
long block of data
...
```

There is nothing unique about any of the blocks of data, but id like to grab out a block based on its position relative to the separators and save it to a new text file. For example, the third block down would include everything between the second and third separators (;).

If anyone has any suggestion for how to do this, it would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume those blocks are of a non-binary type. May I direct your attention to the programs `head` and `tail`.

Comment: Each block in a sense spans two lines.

Comment: I also assumed you are on a system that has those programs. Maybe you ought to add some tags to your question, e.g. Linux and/or Mac, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `awk` for this:

```
awk -v num_block=2 -v RS='\n;\n' 'NR == num_block' /path/to/my/data.txt
```

This displays the block numbered `num_block`.

Explanation: by default, `awk` operates on lines. By redefining RS being a line made of a single semicolon, we instruct it to operate on blocks of text separated by `RS`.

[update] Optimisation: you have a "very large dataset". There is no need to parse the input file once you have found the Nth block, thus let's add a call to `exit`.

```
awk -v num_block=2 -v RS='\n;\n' 'NR == num_block { print; exit }' /path/to/my/data.txt
```

Comment: We had the same idea. I will remove my answer since you posted yours first.

Comment: That's very kind of you @accdias!

Answer (score 1):

You can go with AWk. Here is an exemple to extract the third block :

```sh
cat <datasetfile> | awk '/^;/ { if (flag==1) exit; line++; } /^[^;]/ { if (line==2) { print $0; flag=1; } }'
```